# Log4j custom appender is not called

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am using Log4J 1.2.17 and I tried to create my own appender. **I extended AppenderSkeleton, implemented the overriden methods and declared my appender in my Log4j.properties** - but the appender is never called. What did I miss ?

**Snippet from my appender:**

```
@Override
public void close() {       
}

@Override
public boolean requiresLayout() {
    return false;
}

@Override
protected void append(LoggingEvent event) {
    System.out.println("append !"); // Debug
    appendMessageToSystemLog(event.getMessage().toString()); // Test    
}
```

**And my Log4j properties:**

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, test

### Test ###
log4j.appender.test=util.EventLogger
log4j.appender.test.threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.test.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

Comment: how to you call your logger ? and do you use the INFO level or one underneath ?

Comment: The "normal" appenders work well. I inject my logger via CDI (I have a producer). It's just my own appender that does not work. I use Info, error and debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem: My appender had a private constructor... One of those Mondays...